# gitlab couln'd find remote ref

Tags: gitlab

Gitlab updated from 8.17 to 9.0. The gitlab last version added the current user in front of the URL like http://user.name@gitlab_server/test.git. When I pull from IDE (like Android Studio or Eclipse) appears a error message:

> fatal: couldn't find remote ref

If I read the logs file I found this error:

> Started GET "/android/test.git/HEAD" for (ip) at 2017-03-27
>   06:30:08 +0000 Processing by ApplicationController#route_not_found as
>   */* Parameters: {"unmatched_route"=>"android/test.git/HEAD"} Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)

The problem is maybe correlated with Daylight saving time (DST) change?
What is the problem? How can I solve this issue?
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/30010)

After update to Girlab 9.0 you should configure the sistem with these commands:

> gitlab-ctl reconfigure

followed by a

> gitlab-ctl restart

this solve my problem.